# Cloning functional components in React

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to modify and clone child elements of a component I am creating and recently noticed that the type of `children` I was getting changed depending on how I pass the `children`.

For example if I pass JSX as a children:

```
<MyComponent>
  <div>Hello</div>
</MyComponent>
```

When I check for the `children` structure within `MyComponent` I can see that the object is as follow:

```json
{
  '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: 'div',
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: { children: 'hello' },
  _owner: null,
  _store: {}
}
```

This can be directly used by `React.cloneElement` since `props.children` is present.

If instead I create a functional component like this:

```
const Hello: React.FC = () => <div>hello</div>;
```

And try to use it like this:

```
<MyComponent>
  <Hello/>
</MyComponent>
```

Then the structure of the `children` object becomes this:

```json
{
  '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
  type: [Function: Hello],
  key: null,
  ref: null,
  props: {},
  _owner: null,
  _store: {}
}
```

I can no longer use `React.cloneElement` unless I call `children.type()` which I could not find much documentation on.

Why is this happening and is this expected? And is calling `children.type()` the only way to clone the entire tree of child elements?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-dust-jynt9m?file=/src/App.js works fine for me. Or do you want to clone grandchildren?

Comment: Sorry yeah I should have clarified, I want to clone the entire tree of elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>Hello</div>` is a div, `<Hello/>` is a function that returns a div so obviously they are not the same thing.
`<Hello/>` has an empty object as `props` because it has no children and we didn't pass it an attribute with a value so `props` is `{}`.

what you want really access and clone, is the children of the parent JSX element returned by `<Hello/>` this has nothing to do with its props.
the parent JSX element returned is in fact `children.type()` (what the function returns) this element has childrens wrapped within it (Hello) so `children.type().props.children` is also present there,so you can clone it.

Comment: I get that but is is it safe to call `type()` ? it feels like this isn't meant to be called and are there side effects doing so?

Comment: Using [`cloneElement`](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement) isn't so safe by itself. The official docs say: *Using cloneElement is uncommon and can lead to fragile code.*

Comment: So I guess calling `type` is even worst since it's not even mentionned in the documentation. And there is no other way to achieve this from what I understand. I couldn't find any other React functions

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette yes it is in fact the only way if you want to clone, however the react team suggests [this](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement#alternatives) instead of cloning elements

Comment: @AhmedSbai very interesting, thanks for sharing. Unfortunately in my actual use case I don't have control on the props - it's coming from a webpack loader so my options are a bit limited unless I want to rewrite a new loader which would be quite time consuming